# Consulta trazendo todos os registros, e filtrar os repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Tenha a tabela mov_pallet(alguns registros):

```
movpallet  rua altura   posicao hora        produto     data        pallet
1.424.959   1   C       4       09:30:07    18.342      02.05.2016  456.074            
1.424.960   1   C       4       09:27:07    18.399      05.05.2016  456.182 
1.392.949   1   A       3       13:25:25    71.367      21.03.2016  426.907 
1.388.727   1   A       4       11:41:08    71.711      15.03.2016  423.018 
1.413.547   1   B       2       16:18:41    29.245      19.04.2016  445.891 
1.413.459   1   B       3       14:04:45    29.245      20.04.2016  445.816 
1.411.489   1   C       3       10:11:45    18.399      18.04.2016  443.976 
1.411.600   2   C       3       13:04:41    18.399      18.04.2016  444.081 
1.414.293   3   D       2       11:32:00    29.244      20.04.2016  446.559 
1.414.294   3   D       2       11:32:06    29.244      19.04.2016  446.559 
1.414.285   3   D       3       11:23:24    29.244      21.04.2016  446.552 
1.226.594   6   B       4       14:13:51    1.016       28.07.2015  278.085 
1.424.843   6   B       4       06:58:39    722.841     04.05.2016  456.076 
1.422.912   6   C       2       08:27:17    59.256      03.05.2016  454.337
```

Quero que ela me retorne assim:

```
movpallet  rua altura   posicao hora        produto     data        pallet
1.424.959   1   C       4       09:30:07    18.342      02.05.2016  456.074 (eliminar esse)             
1.424.960   1   C       4       09:27:07    18.399      05.05.2016  456.182 
1.392.949   1   A       3       13:25:25    71.367      21.03.2016  426.907 
1.388.727   1   A       4       11:41:08    71.711      15.03.2016  423.018 
1.413.547   1   B       2       16:18:41    29.245      19.04.2016  445.891 
1.413.459   1   B       3       14:04:45    29.245      20.04.2016  445.816 
1.411.489   1   C       3       10:11:45    18.399      18.04.2016  443.976 
1.411.600   2   C       3       13:04:41    18.399      18.04.2016  444.081 
1.414.293   3   D       2       11:32:00    29.244      20.04.2016  446.559 (esse é igual o proximo mas ele continua, pois o produto e pallet sao iguais)
1.414.294   3   D       2       11:32:06    29.244      19.04.2016  446.559 
1.414.285   3   D       3       11:23:24    29.244      21.04.2016  446.552 
1.226.594   6   B       4       14:13:51    1.016       28.07.2015  278.085 (eliminar esse)
1.424.843   6   B       4       06:58:39    722.841     04.05.2016  456.076 
1.422.912   6   C       2       08:27:17    59.256      03.05.2016  454.337
```

Obs: Tenho N registros nessa tabela.

Comment: o que seria registro repetido? com rua, altura e posicao iguais?

Comment: Os dois registros que você assinalou para eliminar não possuem nada em comum para considerá-los repetidos. Existem outras tabelas associadas? Se for como o Rodrigo mencionou (rua + altura + posicao) nos confirme.

Comment: @RodrigodeBonaSartor isso mesmo a (rua altura e a posicao), são iguais.

Comment: @ismael na verdade os registros que eu marquei nao tem relação entre eles, mas eles tem relacao com proximo registro dele(repetindo a rua,altura, posicao). por exemplo o registro #1.424.959 tem relacao com o 1.424.960 onde (repete a rua.altura, e posicao)

Comment: e o 1.226.594  tem ralação com o 1.424.843 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*
  from mov_pallet a
  left join mov_pallet b 
    on( b.movpallet > a.movpallet
    and b.rua = a.rua
    and b.altura = a.altura
    and b.posicao = a.posicao
    and (b.produto != a.produto or b.pallet != a.pallet) )
where b.movpallet is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, se entendi direito sua questão, tenta algo assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mov_pallet mp
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(movpallet) AS movpallet
               FROM mov_pallet
              GROUP BY rua, altura, posicao) mmp ON mp.movpallet = mmp.movpallet
```

Comment: Deu certo em partes. Mas o registro 1.414.293 teria que continuar.

Comment: Eu tinha respondido antes da sua edição. Se conseguir uma solução eu posto pra você aqui.